# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener'

Tags: javascript, html, typeerror

I have no idea why this does not work. I've seen similar problems on so but they don't fix the problem

That's the HTML code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Java Script 2</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="loginForm">
        <form name="userLogin">
        <input type="text" name="userName" />
        <input type="password" name="userPass" />
        <input type="button" name="login" value="Login" />
        </div>
        <script src = "question_2.js"></script>
        </form>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is the JavaScript

```
var submit = document.getElementById("login");

if(submit!="null"){
submit.addEventListener("click",getLogin);
}

 function getLogin(){
    var nameData = "admin";
    var passData = "admin";
    var userName = document.userLogin.userName.value;
    var pass = document.userLogin.userPass.value;


    if(userName.compareTo(nameData) && pass.compareTo(passData)){
        replace.textContent("Hello there " + nameData);
    }
    else{
        document.write("Try again");
    }
}
```

I have to make the page remove the sign in from when it matches the set login and password to remove the form and display a welcome message. When i open the page and go into the console I get the following error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of
>   nullquestion_2.js:4 (anonymous function)

It targets the action listener I have set for the button but I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: There is no element in your HTML with the id "login", so `.getElementById()` is returning `null`.

Comment: [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) looks for an element with a matching [`id` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) rather than by `name`.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you have no Element with the id:"login". Thats why submit is null.

You should give the input:

```
<input type="button" name="login" value="Login" />
```

the appropriate id. And, another thing:

```
if(submit!="null")
```

I assume you want to check "submit" against the actual value: null, not the string "null". You should write your if-statement it as follows:

```
if(submit!==null)
```

This way, you check submit against the null-Object, and you do it type-safe, that means if sumbit is not null, but for some strange reason undefined, you will still do the correct check. Read [Steve Johnsons Blog Post](http://saladwithsteve.com/2008/02/javascript-undefined-vs-null.html) on undefined vs. null, if this is somehow new to you.

Answer (score 1):

You have no element with ID "login"

```
var submit = document.getElementById("login");

if(submit){
submit.addEventListener("click",getLogin);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just simply add defer to your script src at .html like

`<script src="slide 52.js" defer></script>`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

From your HTML code above, you did not define the ID you making reference to.
you made reference to ID (`login`) on this line `var submit = document.getElementById("login");`

While the only `Id` you had in the `HTML` was `"loginform"`.
you can correct that line or simply add the `"login"` Id to the desired `HTML` attribute and it will surely work as desired.